# Call to method ends up in completely different one

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, wxwidgets

I have a strange problem which appears in wxWidgets libraries and which can be reproduced easily in debugger. It does not seem to be wxWidgets-specific, so I'm asking this here.

I perform some kind of non-standard initialisation. During this initialisation a method wxAppBase::Initialize() is called. wxAppBase is the base class of my own App-class. Within wxAppBase::Initialize() an other method OnInitGui() is called, this method exists in wxAppBase as well as in my derived class.

And here is the problem: In Debug Build, everthing works well, OnInitGui() is executed as expected. But in Release-build I never reach OnInitGui() method but end up in a completely different one which does not have anything to do with OnInitGui(). So it seems an illegal jump is performed.

All pointers seem to be valid and this happens in wxWidgets library completely.

Anybody an idea what could cause such a behaviour and how one could fix this?

Every hint/idea/suggestion is welcome.

Comment: It's a bit hard to give useful advice without an MCVE.  However, code that behaves differently in a debugger (presumably compiled with optimisation off) and in release mode is - more often than not - a consequence of some form of undefined behaviour.   That might mean, for example, that your claim that all pointers seem valid is mistaken.

Comment: Peter: there are a lot of pointers floating around and I of course could not check all of them. So I hope/guess they are valid, at least I could not see something strange.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bad build. Clean everything and rebuild both the library and your application using exactly the same compiler and compiler options and the problem will probably just disappear.

Comment: This was not the solution. I already tried rebuilding, rebuilding with different optimisation settings and rebuilding with a different compiler version - result is still the same strange jump.